# The origin of the Moon: Short story

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, moon

This is a Matheson-like story where the human race, once widespread in the galaxy, was beaten back to our home planet after a devastating interstellar war. The aliens won the war and the Moon -- an artificial monitoring station -- was moved into orbit around the Earth to ensure that humanity would stay put, by a final treaty. (Yeah, I know, even as a kid I thought the Moon was improbably large and massive for this purpose.) Our species collapsed into barbarism but the aliens kept their end of the bargain and simply continued to watch across the millennia. I don't recall further details. What WAS that story, anyway?

There was also a comic-book story with a very similar plot, but that is a different question. The story appeared in an English-language anthology read probably in the 1960s, possibly as late as the 70s.

Comment: I've read quite a few of Richard Matheson's stories, and I'm not at all sure what quality you mean by "Matheson-like". Please explain.

Comment: Hmm. Matheson had a twisted (occasionally farcical) sense of humor. In this case, it may be more accurate to say that he appreciated surprise twists in the narrative. Things (e.g., the Moon, the history of the human race) are not what they seem at first. Aside from that, his stories often end in tragedy or helplessness; you can't count on a happy resolution (humanity finds itself restricted to its home planet for past crimes none of us remember). Both of these features are present in this story. Brian Aldiss is another author who could write like this, but he wrote in a more literary style.

Comment: It seems like the description of these two stories is almost *exactly* the same. Are they different in any way, or is it like that one is an adaptation of the  other?

Comment: @Adamant: Yes. I read the comic book first. When I read the short story, I remember being surprised by the similarity. Since the short story could have been anthologized years after its original publication, it would not surprise me if the comic book were adapted from the short story, Possibly the reverse. I've wracked my mind for more detail, but it doesn't seem to survive.

Comment: If they're really the same, they technically need only one question.

Comment: @Adamant, that could cause problems, if one person answers about the comic book and another person answers about the short story which answer should be accepted?

Comment: @Adamant: Similar, not identical. They are not in the same format, and presumably would count in the ISFDB as two separate publications. They may well have different author, title, and date. So why borrow trouble? If they prove to be identical after research, then the two can be collapsed together at that time.

Comment: For people coming to this in the weeks, months, and years to come: the people above are discussing https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/212791/21871 .