# The origin of the Moon: Comic book

Tags: story-identification, comics, moon

This is story where the human race, once widespread in the galaxy, was beaten back to our home planet after a devastating interstellar war. The aliens won the war and the Moon -- an artificial monitoring station -- was moved into orbit around the Earth to ensure that humanity would stay put, by a final treaty. (Yeah, I know, even as a kid I thought the Moon was improbably large and massive for this purpose.) Our species collapsed into barbarism but the aliens kept their end of the bargain and simply continued to watch across the millennia. The cartoon included a picture of the Moon being moved into place; craters were rendered as the outward part of hidden sensing devices. Can this tale be identified?

There was also a Matheson-like short story with a very similar plot, but that is a different question. The comic book, almost certainly American, appeared in English in the 1950s or 60s.

Comment: There are some similarities to the *Outlanders* manga, but that didn't appear in English until the 1990s.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlanders_(manga)

Comment: Possibly *Jeff Hawke*? The time frame matches.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeff_Hawke

Answer (score 1):

Tengen Toppa Gurren Lagann, I think you refer to the episode 21 or 22, the main plot seems similar, but its revealed later in the anime

https://myanimelist.net/anime/2001/Tengen_Toppa_Gurren_Lagann

Comment: OP is looking for an English-language comic book from the 60s, not an anime. I'm sure if they'd watched Gurren Lagann (or read the manga adaptation), they would have remembered a *lot* more than just the part about the moon being artificial - for example, the part where it transforms into a gigantic spaceship.

Comment: Well, it's interesting to hear about the comparison, anyway; sometimes it turns out that an artist or author borrowed an idea from another. As to memories from the 60s, it's the books that were owned and reread over a period of years that I remember with clarity. I have no trouble remembering jokes from Mad Magazine's parody of _Star Trek_ (December 1967), for instance, and there were few surprises when I saw it again recently after a gap of 48 years. But the plots of most comic books have faded beyond recall.